# ASP.NET core - middleware on MVC

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, middleware

I try to create an asp.net core web api on macOS.

But my middleware isn't called on mvc-call.

My Config:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, BackendDbContext context)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        //app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>();

        BackendDbInitializer.Init(context);
    }
```

And my Middleware:

```
public class AuthMiddleware 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoke......................");

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

When i do a HTTP-request, that doesn't match a controller request. The middleware class is called.

How can i set up that the middleware class is only called on a mvc-request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use middleware as MVC filters:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [MiddlewareFilter(typeof(AuthMiddleware))]
    public IActionResult Index()  
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In this case, `AuthMiddleware` will run each time the action method `Index` is called.

**PS**: You need to install this package ([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/))

[more info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/) (see Middleware as MVC filters section)

Comment: I am really new to MVS i think your method is inside a controller? But i don't want to add the annotations on each method, because i want this on each method.

Comment: @Flo I have updated my answer. You can also apply this filter on your controller.

Comment: Okay i will use the middleware as auth. And i want to call it on every rest controller and every method. Can i not configure it global?

Comment: @Flo It depends, If you need to handle cross-cutting business and application concerns you can use Filter instead, But if you need something globally then you can use Middlware. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#filters-vs-middleware

Comment: Yes i want to use Middleware, but on the MVC-controller the middleware is ignored

Comment: @Flo define your middleware before `app.UseMvc();`

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. Do you know if i can access the annotations from the controller method in Invoke-method?