# MVC with REST and client authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, http, authentication

I've got a working model of an MVC application working with Authentication (using Azure B2C).  In order to authenticate my client, I need to add a 'Bearer' token to the header like so:

```
    public async Task<string> GetValuesAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(this.serviceOptions.BaseUrl, UriKind.Absolute) };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Bearer",
            await this.GetAccessTokenAsync());

        return await client.GetStringAsync("api/products");
    }
```

I don't want to create a proxy for every CRUD operation I have and I want to use the Kendo UI products which have a pretty slick RESTful API.  Is there some way to automatically add the bearer token to the header in every HTTP operation so I don't have to make proxies and can use a proper RESTful API?

Comment: Are you using `.NetCore`? For core you can use middlewear selectively on controllers/actions like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146879/asp-net-core-middleware-on-mvc
Otherwise you can create a filter and override either `OnResultExecuted` or `OnResultExecuting` to insert the HTTP header (not sure which).

Comment: Are you using `.NetCore`

Comment: this telerik thread may help you get to the answer you are looking for: https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-authorization-header-for-transport-read

Comment: @Wurd - Yes, I am.  Let's remove the issue of Kendo UI.  Is there some general purpose way to modify the header of each outgoing HTTP request?  Your first response seems to be dealing with the server code, which is working just fine.  This is a question about the client side of this conversation.

Comment: If you are using a client side JS framework, like Angular, then easily yes. But otherwise I'm not sure, you would have to write some JS to listen/intercept HTTP calls or explicitly add it somehow.